Nominatim Openstreet API giving 403 error
I'm using openstreet api but currently I'm running into an error where I'm getting 403 error. I've looked into the docs and it said to provide valid headers. I provided the headers but still I'm getting the same error.
"Client error: GET https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=32.2074&lon=76.3344 resulted in a 403 Forbiddenresponse:\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Access blocked</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Access blocked</h1>\n\n<p>You have been blocked because you (truncated...)\n" 
Here's the code:
      try {
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse', [
                'query' => [
                    'format' => 'json',
                    'lat' => $latitude,
                    'lon' => $longitude
                ],
                "headers" => [
                    'User-Agent' => 'MyApp/1.0 (https://myapp.dev.net; myapp@gmail.com)', 
                    'Referer' => 'https://myapp.dev.net'
                ]
            ]);
        } 
        catch(RequestException $e) {
            echo "AN ERROR OCCURED: ".$e->getMessage();
        };
    ```


You have been blocked because you (truncated...) - go and see that you get the untruncated error message first of all.
